# C strlen wrong answer

Tags: c, char, strlen

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code

```
char* readString() {

    char* result;
    char line[SIZE];

    if(! fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin))
        fprintf(stderr, "error\n");

    //printf 1
    printf("line length = %lu\n", strlen(line));

    result = line;

    return result;
}

int main() {

    char* myWord = readString();
    unsigned long len = (unsigned)strlen(myWord);

    //printf 2
    printf("myWord length = %lu\n", len);

    return 0;
}
```

If printf1 and printf2 are both uncommented then I get true length. For example for word 'hello' I have output

```
line length = 6
myWord length = 6
```

but If I only comment printf1, for the same word 'hello' I have

```
myWord length = 16
```

Comment: You can't return a pointer to a local variable (here your `line[SIZE]`) safely, that's undefined behavior in C when you access that returned value. As a quick fix, make your local `static line[SIZE]` but that might not be the optimal solution for your problem.

Comment: Assuming C99, the proper way to print a value of type `size_t` (which is the return type of `strlen()`, it's *not* an `int`) is `%zu`.

Comment: @unwind: Or you can use `%lu` and cast to `unsigned long`. (Or `%d` and `int` if you're sure the string isn't very long.)

Comment: @KeithThompson True, of course. The code does that, too. :)

Comment: @KeithThompson On some platforms, `size_t` is larger than `long`.

Comment: @larsmans: It's certainly possible for `size_t` to be wider than `long`, but I don't know of any actual compilers for which that's the case. Do you have an example? (You need to use `unsigned long` if you need C90 compatibility. It will fail only if the actual length of the string exceeds `ULONG_MAX`, which must be at least 2**32-1.) Of course `%zu` is ideal *if* you can safely assume all relevant implementations support it.

Comment: @KeithThompson I don't have an MSVC to check this, but IIRC on 64-bit Windows `long` is 32 bits and `size_t` is 64.

Comment: @larsmans: You're right (I just checked).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code exhibits **undefined behavior**. You are returning a pointer to a variable declared on the stack. In this case, `line` or `result`.

Two possible fixes include:

1. Pass the `char line[SIZE];` variable to the `readString()` function.
2. Allocate the memory for `line` on the heap using `malloc()`.

Comment: or 3.) Declare it static: `static char line[SIZE];`

Comment: @Marian: I really don't like the static option. It promotes new C programmers writing code they don't understand, and then they call `readString()` again, and they are all confused why the first string changed.

Comment: @sharth: Then they don't understand `static` in the first place and shouldn't use it. People who are well aware of `static` can make very sensible use of it.

Comment: sharth is right.. using `static` here would lead to weird regressions later on

Answer (score 1):

You return a dynamic value (stack allocated) which is deleted by `return`. You should either

- use a static string, but it won't support multithreading nor recursively
- let the caller define the string as

  ```
  char * readstring(char * line, size_t size) {
  // Your stuff
      char * result = fgets(line, size);
  // ...
      return result;
  }
  ```